# Custom NativeActivity to show Arguments on a rehosted designer

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I've a custom NativeActivity with a bunch of InArguments. It will always be the root activity when the client is editing it's workflow on a rehosted designer. So far so good.

The problem is, although InArguments are showed on PropertyInspector, no 'Arguments' tab is showed. I understand why it happens but I really want to make this NativeActivity to be the root activity for a variety of reasons: I can customize it on my way, I can give it a custom Designer, etc.

How can I had argument properties to a NativeActivity in a way that they're showed on 'Arguments' tab within the designer making them available and allowing the client to do whatever he/she wants with the InArguments without the "'argumentName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level" think?

What I've tried:

- Just like variables, where we can use a Collection{Variable} and the designer recognizes it as the place where the activity variables are, I've tried Collection{Argument}. No luck!
- Simply write InArgument within NativeActivity. They're showed on Property Inspector but can't be used within the workflow through the designer. Again they cannot be resolved and"'argumentName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level" happens.
- Bind previous InArguments to RuntimeArguments through CacheMetadata() using metadata.AddArgument() and metadata.Bind(). No luck whatsoever.

I known that ActivityBuilder is probably the best way to solve this. I successfully tried something like:

```
ActivityBuilder builder = new ActivityBuilder();
builder.Implementation = new MyCustomNativeActivity();

DynamicActivityProperty property = new DynamicActivityProperty()
{
 Name = "TestArg",
 Type = typeof(InArgument<string>),
};

builder.Properties.Add(property);

Designer.Load(builder);
```

But this leads to bad code because I've to had the arguments when I'm loading the designer. This prevents me from having a library with my custom activities separated from the forms code itself. Mainly because ActivityBuilder is a sealed class, much like DynamicActivity which, I assume, would work too.

Is there any way to simulate the ActivityBuilder behaviour, that allow to add properties at codetime, but using a NativeActivity which can be easily inherited and customized?

I hope I've made myself clear.

P.S.: I also took a look at IExecutionProperty but I didn't understand well how it works, what's its purpose and if it can be applied here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my problem is known and there's no plan to support it on next WF releases.

Links with explanations and a few workarounds: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/68dd6273-f431-4af1-b048-d603a4ad2a75) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/b540c6d4-0f07-41ac-a64c-e37242ba9018).

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure bout your problem here. That said only yesterday I solved another problem by deriving from Activity directly and not using NativeActivity for a root of the workflow. Not sure if it will help in your case but it might just do it.

So something like this:

```
public class RootActivity : Activity
{
    public InArgument<string> TestArg {get; set;}

    public RootActivity(Activity child)
    {
        Implementation = () => child;
    }
}
```

Note: Typed in notepad so not tested and be careful with typos.

Comment: My problem is that neither NativeActivity nor, in this case, Activity have the concept of Properties (or members, whatever they use to be called). Because of that I can't build a custom activity that, after being loaded by the designer, show the 'Arguments' tab, again because arguments are properties and they don't exist on those abstract base activities.

Comment: Oh, and ActivityBuilder, much like DynamicActivity, are the only ones I known having the concept of properties, but they are sealed classes which, of course, can't be inherited. For me is enough to had InArguments properties at codetime.

Comment: Bottom-line I want a custom activity which can be the root to have access to all the goodies that that brings including the ability to have InArguments. By my understanding that's just plane impossible because of the way WF4 works.

Comment: Just to clarify my scenario: I've a library with all my activities including that custom activity. That activity would have a pre-defined number of InArguments available to use and it would always be the root activity for the workflows build by the client. Because of all these restrictions the root have to always be an ActivityBuilder. This leads to very messy code because I've to specify InArguments when I'm constructing ActivityBuilder on forms side and not on the CustomActivity itself. It seems that I must resign myself to this situation.

Comment: I am afraid I don't have a good solution for you here. Sorry.

Comment: It seems that my problem is known and there's no plans to support it: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/68dd6273-f431-4af1-b048-d603a4ad2a75) and [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/b540c6d4-0f07-41ac-a64c-e37242ba9018). Thank you anyway